# Not deleting the proper lines from text file

Tags: java

I have been trying to create a method that searches through a text file, finds the data that I want to delete, deletes three lines before the data, the data, and three lines after the data. The code I am using:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DeleteData {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        //ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String configurationString ="20\r\n" + 
                "21\r\n" + 
                "22\r\n" + 
                "23\r\n" + 
                "24"; 
        deleteFromFile(configurationString);

    }
    public static void writeToFile(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("write.txt"));
            for(String x:list)
            {
                writer.write(x);
                writer.newLine();
            }
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void deleteFromFile(String search) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File inputFile = new File("write.txt");
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(inputFile);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            list.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(list.toString());

        String textStr[] = search.split("\\r\\n|\\n|\\r");

        for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
        {
            if(i < list.size()-3 && list.get(i+3).equals(textStr[3]))
            {
                list.remove(i);
                list.remove(i+1);
                list.remove(i+2);
                list.remove(i+3);
                list.remove(i+4);
                list.remove(i+5);
                list.remove(i+6);
                writeToFile(list);
                i+=7;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
}
```

The file write.txt before running the program:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
>   27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
>   50

and I am getting this after running it:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33
>   35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50

Instead of getting

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
>   35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50

Comment: My first expression is... you have to delete backward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove shifts all of the elements after the index:

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-

To achieve what you want, remove the elements by highest index first:

```
list.remove(i+6);
list.remove(i+5);
list.remove(i+4);
list.remove(i+3);
list.remove(i+2);
list.remove(i+1);
list.remove(i);
```

Then the output from your program is:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]

Answer (score 1):

Each time you do `list.remove(i)`, list actually collapses, and the next line becomes the one with `i` index:

before remove:

```
 i  line
 10 10
 11 11
 12 12
```

after:

```
i  line
10 11
11 12
12 13
```

That's why you drop lines interleaved; you should either call `remove(i)` 7 times (but you don't check `i` against `list.size()` properly!), or reverse the order.

---

Still I see the bigger issues with the code. First, it's not clear why do you have five lines set as your `searchTerm`, but only check the input against the single - fourth - one with `list.get(i+3).equals(textStr[3])` expression. Second, it's not clear why do you even need to put all the lines of the source file in `list` first with this:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
   list.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

... when you can check the conditions *before* adding it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call list.remove, you're actually modifying the size of the list because Java will resize the list and shift future elements down. So when you call `list.remove(i+1)` after `list.remove(i)`, you're actually removing the element two spaces after the previous call.

What you should do is start with `list.remove(i+6)` and move backwards until you reach `list.remove(i)`. This preserves the correct indices.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because every time you perform a `list.remove(i)` the remaining elements are shifted to the left, and the next `list.remove(i+1)`, will remove the one after the one you were expecting. You can review this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-)

Hope it helps